# duplicated tab in form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, forms

[image]

```
        $fieldset->addField('media_gallery', 'note',
        [
            'label' => '',
            'title' => __('Media Gallery'),
            'name'  => 'media_gallery',
            // 'required' => true,
            'text'      => $this->getContentHtml(),
        ]
    );
```

i have a tab like this. how can I duplicated it in a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Create an overridden class to the original class in your custom module.
2. Call the original method using the keyword parent::methodName
3. Add the new tab.