# Make the same multiple tab work separately in form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, gallery-image

[image]

```
        $fieldset->addField('media_gallery', 'note',
        [
            'label' => '',
            'title' => __('Media Gallery'),
            'name'  => 'media_gallery',
            // 'required' => true,
            'text'      => $this->getContentHtml(),
        ]
    );
```

I have a tab like this. how can I duplicate it in a custom module? and 
Make these 2 tabs work separately. please help me. thank you.

Comment: Did you try my approach in your old post?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285533/duplicated-tab-in-form-magento-2/285542#285542

Comment: Yes, but I want it to work independently. Thanks for your reply.